# Visual Studio Code reporting syntax issue with valid regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code is reporting a syntax issue with this regex in `javascript`:

```
let regex;
regex = /^https:\/\/[^\/]+/[A-Za-z]+-[\d\D]{4}-Report$/g;
```

Specifically, squiggly red underline beneath \d and {

Before I start ripping out extensions, **does anyone see anything obvious?**

Comment: What is the purpose of `[\d\D]` ?

Comment: @epascarello It is a workaround that matches any char and is equal to `[^]` in JS regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a missing escaping backslash here:

```
/^https:\/\/[^\/]+/[A-Za-z]+-[\d\D]{4}-Report$/g
                  ^
```

So it should be:

```
/^https:\/\/[^\/]+\/[A-Za-z]+-[\d\D]{4}-Report$/g
```

Comment: Duh, thanks. I'll accept the answer in 6 minutes from now.